# Is there an RFC on EML file formats?

Tags: email, rfc, eml, email-formats

Basically, I'm attempting to work with EML files and I want to know if these files are pretty standard across different email servers... basically, is there an RFC on EML files just like there is one for email addresses and other topics?

---

I guess I can be a bit more specific to get a better understanding of what I need. I am scanning an Exchange mailbox and saving out the eml files from the following property: `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.MimeContent.Content`.

Once I have an eml file I want to know if there is a standard way it is formatted. That's pretty much it. I asked about an RFC because I figured the standard would be explained in an RFC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.eml files are *usually* stored in [rfc822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) format

but afaik, there is no official definition

Comment: which is obsoleted by https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5322 (and 2822). Just got here from google

Answer (score 7):

This one expands on rfc822 and covers MIME entities and other content:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt

Answer (score 2):

There are several conventional storage formats for email messages and mailboxes, but there's no single standard for them. RFC's tend to be written about what goes over the wire, not what goes on inside the box.